# Editing the description in the dashboard view of a Carto map once the map has been published?

Tags: carto

It appears that once you write a description in the dashboard view of a Carto map (where it says "Add description...") the text is un-editable. Is there a way to edit the text?

The map on the left shows before text is entered, the map on the right shows after text has been entered and cannot be edited.[image]

Comment: Are you using CARTO Editor or BUILDER? Are you referring to Editor's text overlay elements or map metadata description? We need more information to help you here.

Comment: I'm using builder, I am referring to when you view your maps on the dashboard and each map says "Add description...".  I wrote a description, published the map, and now I need to edit the description. Is that possible?

Comment: Could you update your post with that info? Also, could you add screenshots/gifs of the place you cannot update the description?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot edit an existing description or tags from your dashboard. You will need to open the map and change the metedata.

1-Open the map submenu and click on `Edit metadata...`.

[image: map-submenu]

2-Edit the `DESCRIPTION` and save it.

[image: metadata]

Editing your map info from the dashboard is a nice feature to have so I will pass your feedback to CARTO's Product Managers and designers (disclaimer: I work at CARTO).